# Questions about performance for Merging Data-Set in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, sql-server-2000, .net-1.1

> ASP.NET 1.1 / VB.NET / SQL 2000

I am generation report using crystal reports 10... the report is working fine but the problem that it is taking too long to load and display the data.

> **What I am doing is:** 
>    I have two tables (one to many). I am getting all records from the first table and storing it in a table in my dataset... then I am getting all records from the second table depending on the ID from the first table. then storing it in another table in the *dataset*.
>
> After that, I merge both tables in dataset by doing for each loop to merge each record to its related id.
>
> Finally, bind it to the report
>
> *The merging process takes 2 minutes!!*

.

> - What can I do?
> - Is there a better way to do the same thing?
> - Can I control the range of records in my SQL statement?

### Important

I can't put my code, because lot of code's there , It's really confusing to all .

Comment: Why don't you just create a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) object?

Comment: @Steve , Is it supported in 1.1 framework ? Am using 1.1 framework

Comment: The class DataRelation is present from the beginning. So it is supported, however, I am not sure about your report. If it expects everything in a flat table it is possibile that you need to rewrite it to take advantage of relations built in the dataset. Sorry but I am not an expert of Crystal Reports.

Comment: It's okay ! But i will think about your opinion , Thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have not supplied much information but let me give you an exmaple of some code that you should be able to modify to your purpose.

```vb
Dim SQL1 As String = "SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1 where Field2 = 7" 'Standard SQL
Dim SQL2 As String = "SELECT Field3, Field4, Field1 FROM Table2 Where Field1 in (SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 where Field2 = 7)" 'This SQL contains a nested select to get the child data for only the records that match the parent
'A neat feature, combine them into 1 SQL statement that will produce 2 tables in your dataset in one call
Dim SQL3 As String = SQL1 & ";" & SQL2
Dim CN As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connection string here")
Dim DS As New DataSet
Dim DA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL3, CN)
CN.Open()
DA.Fill(DS)
CN.Close()
```

See notes in the code for explainations of what is happening. Based on your TAGs of VB.net, Sql Server and Net1.1, this should all work for you.